# CakePHP 2.3 adding new folder to load models not working

Tags: cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

I'm using the following code in my bootstrap.php (as explained [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#App%3a%3abuild)) to load models also from another folder:

```
App::build(array('Model' => array('/my/path/to/models')));
```

This *seems* to work. I have a model *MyModel* inside that folder, which I include in the controller I want to use it like usually:

```
var $uses = array('MyModel');
```

If I print **App::objects('Model')**, the model *MyModel* is shown in the list, so I assume it's loaded correctly. However, when I try to use the model (i.e. **$this->MyModel->find()** it never finds anything, it always returns an empty array.

Note that if I put the same exact model (*MyModel*) in the typical models folder (**app/Model/**) then it all works fine.

What am I missing to make this work?

**EDIT**

Ok, so it seems that the problem is in the connection to the database when the model is placed in that folder outside **app**. With the code shown above, Cake finds the model. However, when I do a **find()**, I get a **missing table** error for the datasource (**default** in this case).

Is it possible that the model isn't loading the correct database configuration because that configuration is inside the **app/Config** folder? How can I make that model load that configuration? If I have to put that configuration somewehre else (maybe in the same *outside* folder?) I can do that, but how do I tell the model to find it?

**EDIT 2**

I can see better what the problem is now. If I put a model in a different folder (other than **app/Model**) and use **App::build()** to set the path of that new folder, Cake finds it, there's no doubt (I use **App::objects('Model')** and the model is listed with all the other models from **app/Model**).

However, it's like Cake is not actually reading what's inside that model class, or at least not everything. It seems to read the **$useDbConfig** variable, but it ignores **$useTable** and any function I have defined in that model. Example of my model:

```
class Usuario extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Usuario';
var $primaryKey = 'id_usuario'; 
var $useDbConfig = 'BD_ControlAcceso';

function createTempPassword($len) {

    //some code
}
}
```

If I do a **$this->Usuario->find('all')**, it returns all the records correctly. However, if I call **$this->Usuario->createTempPassword(7)** I get a **Database Error**.

I have another model (MyModel) in that same folder with a **$useTable = 'mytable'**. If I don a **find()** on it, I get an error saying that ***mytable* table could not be found**. However, if I do **$this->MyModel->useTable = 'mytable'** then it works fine.

How is this possible? What's going on here?

**EDIT 3**

I just want to add that I've done extensive testing and the issue is clear: Cake "knows" that the model is in the external folder (confirmed by printing **App::objects('Model')**, the model is listed there, and if I remove it from that folder then it's not listed). But even though it knows it's there, **it ignores whatever is inside the model file**. I've tried all the methods below to load the model but none of them worked. Is this a bug in CakePHP? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `App::uses('MyModel', 'Model');`?

Comment: where exactly? I tried putting it on top of the controller page, but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `App::uses('MyModel', 'Model')` and is should go before the class declaration like so:

```
<?php

App::uses('MyModel', 'Model');
App::uses('AppController','Controller');
class UsersController extends AppController {
 // controller class
}
```

Another thing to try is loading the model where you need it:

```
$this->loadModel('MyModel');
```

The other thing you can try is the Model instantiation in the top of your model class. Try updating your model to:

```
App::uses('AppModel','Model');
class Usuario extends AppModel {

var $name = 'Usuario';
var $primaryKey = 'id_usuario'; 
var $useDbConfig = 'BD_ControlAcceso';

function createTempPassword($len) {

    //some code
}
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, I'll give this a try. One question though, should I also put the `App::build(array('Model' => array('/my/path/to/models')));` in the bootstrap?

Comment: If your model is in your App/Model folder, no. Cake will already be able to find it. If you are putting it somewhere other than the App/Model folder then yes. Cake still needs to know where to find the model if it not already in the model folder.

Comment: this is making me go crazy... So now it seems that it was actually loading the model from the external "Model" folder... so to do a test, I removed the **Usuario** model from both "Model" folders (the one in the "app/Model" folder and the one in the external "Model" folder). Well, even without that model, the login function it's still working and finding a user!!! How is that possible? It can't be because it's using the default database configuration, since this **Usuario** model uses a different database. So how in the world is Cake using this model if I don't have it there???

Comment: Cache? You may want to delete all of your cache files (look in the app/tmp folder for the cache) and see if it still works. My bet is no.

Comment: the app/tmp/cache folder has 3 subfolders (model, persistent and views) and they're all empty. I also have `Configure::write('Cache.disable', true);` in the core.php config file while in development, so I guess that's the reason they're empty...